# mov and add operand in assembler code?

Tags: assembly, x86

We are using gdb to debug some lines of code. There are two lines we aren't sure what it does:

```
mov -0x8(%edx) %eax
add -0x4(%edx) %eax
```

I am always confused about parentheses in assembly. Is there any tutorial or reference out there?

Comment: You can switch gdb to intel syntax mode using `set disassembly-flavor intel`.  Here is a quick [at&t cheat sheet](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/brennan/brennan_att_inline_djgpp.html).

Answer (score 1):

`mov -0x8(%edx) %eax` is equivalent to `mov eax, [edx-8]`. (loads eax from memory)

`add -0x4(%edx) %eax` is equivalent to `add eax, [edx-4]`. (loads eax from memory)